# TypeScript type extension with methods

Tags: typescript, types, extension-methods

Suppose I have an externally defined class (sorry for not specifying earlier)

```
export class A {
    a: string
    b: number

    public foo() { }
}
```

And I want to add a method `bar` to class `A` globally, how would I do that in TypeScript? In JavaScript I know you can simply do `A.prototype.bar = function() { ... }` but in TypeScript that causes multiple issues with it not being a recognized property of class `A` in both definition and all usages. So I'm wondering how do I do this in TypeScript just being able to run `objectOfTypeA.bar()`?

Comment: You'll need to use `declare`.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "globally", though? Is `class A` yours? If so, then why not just add the `bar()` method to the `class`? It will still be a part of the `export` so every file (that has an `import` for it) can use it...

Comment: _"but in TypeScript that causes multiple issues with it not being a recognized property of class A in both definition and all usages."_ - that's typically when you use the `any` type .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I want to add a method `bar()` to `class A` globally, how would I do that in TypeScript?

Assuming `class A` is yours, then just add `bar()` - there's no point to doing anything else because any `.ts` or `.js` file that could manipulate the `A.prototype` will already have to `import` it anyway.

```js
export class A {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    foo() { }
    bar() { }

}
```

---

Whereas if `class A` is not an `export`ed type, but is an *old-school* "`global`"-scoped `class` or Constructor-`function`, then you will still need to use `A.prototype` manipulation (probably using `any` in TypeScript) but you can still codify your changes [with a `declare` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html):

In (modern) TypeScript you'll probably only encounter `declare` if you peer inside `.d.ts` files from `@types` libraries, or the `lib.dom.d.ts` in your TypeScript install folder - but it's also used to allow TypeScript to work with *uncooperative* libraries...

You can also have multiple `declare` statements for the exact same type: that works [because TypeScript will merge them together for you](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

### Module Augmentation:

Also, doing this for patching external *module* code is known as "module augmentation":

**Uncooperative.js:**

```
export class A {
    foo() { }
}
```

**You.ts:**

```
// First, import it:
import { A } from "./uncooperative";

// Second: extend the interface of `class A` with a declaration:
// Yes, you use an `interface` type to extend a `class` type.
declare module "./uncooperative" {
    
    interface A {
        bar(): void;
    }
}

// Third: you do the actual monkey-patching, with the `any` type to avoid TS errors that we don't care about here:
( A as any ).prototype.bar = function() {
    window.location = 'https://leekspin.com/';
};
```

### Global Augmentation:

If you're working with a `.js` file that doesn't use Modules: good ol' fashioned *global*-scoped files, just like they were back in 1996, then you need to use the `declare global` statement:

**Uncooperative.js:**

```
function MacGuffin() {
    this.fieldA = 'a';
}
MacGuffin.prototype.runTurboEncabulator = function( arg1 ) {
    
};
```

**You.ts:**

```
// Nothing to import, just make your declarations:

declare global {
    interface MacGuffin {
        doSomethingElse(): void;
    }
}

// Then monkey-patch it:

MacGuffin.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {
    window.location = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKfKtXYLG78';
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a class like `Array`?
EDIT: Found it. Just declare an interface with name `Array`

Comment: @asdafadsfadsfdaf I'll admit that I'm unsure what the difference between `interface Array { }` and `interface Array<T> { }` might be - if any.